# Check if file names are the same using Applescript

Tags: applescript

How would I go about checking if a file (an alias called theFile) has the same name as any other files in another folder?

I would like to have an Applescript look through all of the files in the folder and has a if and else as a result if it does match one of the names or doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Choose a folder
- Get the name of `theFile`
- Get a list of all file names in the folder
- Check if the list contains the name of `theFile`

---

```
set theFile to alias ...

set theFolder to choose folder
tell application "System Events"
    set theFileName to name of theFile
    set otherFileNames to name of files of theFolder
end tell

set fileNameExists to otherFileNames contains theFileName
```

Comment: A cute little one-line version of your script: `tell application "System Events" to return theFile's container is the folder named (choose folder)`